# DVI monitor adaptor

Tags: mac, display, cable, adapter

I have a Mac mini 2014 (port HDMI and thunderbolt) and I want to connect it to a DVI only monitor. Which port is the best option? Should I use an adapter or all in one cable?
Thanks

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. Just use any HDMI to DVI adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the HDMI port, because HDMI and DVI are actually almost the same thing. The only differences are the plug shape and HDMI being able to transfer audio while DVI can't. Other than that they're identical, so you can find completely passive adaptors between the two.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they are far from identical, but HDMI guarantees fallback to DVI-D if the display doesn't report HDMI capabilities in EDID. So you're correct that using HDMI is the way to go.

Comment: HDMI and DVI have almost nothing in common. DVI supports both analog and digital signals while HDMI is purely digital.